# How can I find out how many times a webpage has been visited on someone else's site?

Tags: hyperlink, tracking

I need to see how many times people click on links to specific webpages on the web. Are there tools that can track this? Not on sites I own, so not google Analytics.

Example:
Someone is on Cake.com and click on a link that goes to cookies.com/yummy
And not that it just goes to cookies.com, but specifically to that yummy page.

And please don't use technical words. 
Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in this example you own Cake.com, but not cookies.com, right?

If so, you can track clicks on your site that direct to other sites with Google Analytics events. This is easily done with Google Tag Manager, where you can create a tag to fire an event any time someone clicks a link that does not match your hostname/hostnames. This needs to be your option if you do not want to do anything technical.

On events in GTM:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716?hl=en

If you have on-page analytics, you will need to add a line of code to all external that sends a hit to Google Analytics. Below is an example (it would be one line on the "onclick=" of the link, but I added newlines for readability here):

```
ga('send',
   'event',
   'Outbound Links', 
   'on page: ' + document.location.pathname, 
   'link: ' + this.href)
```

It would show up in the Events report as:

**Event Category:** Outbound Links

**Event Action:** on page: [page the link is located on]

**Event Category:** link: [the outbound link]

More info here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en